# MIPS count for throughput?

Tags: performance, throughput

I was reading [this question about FLOPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592657/what-counts-as-a-flop) and I agree with all that, but then how should we measure the performance of a program that does not contain floats? Should we go for MIPS (million instructions per seconds? If so, how to count them? Can someone give a small code and explain how to count MIPS?

Comment: Could you clarify the need to use CUDA and OpenCL tags?

Comment: Because I am interested in GPGPU performance more than in CPU, although throughput is throughput no matter what type of processor. Should I remove them then?

Comment: Since the same question could be applied to any computing hardware, I think that these tags are not needed, unless you have some CUDA-specific question to ask.